# How to map a json list in flutter using JSONSerializable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to map a json list in my application using JSON Serializable. But I am not able to map it.

Following is the response from the API:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Countries Lists",
    "count": 250,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Aland Islands"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Albania"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Algeria"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "American Samoa"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Andorra"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Angola"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Anguilla"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Antarctica"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Antigua And Barbuda"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Argentina"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Armenia"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Aruba"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Australia"
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Austria"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Azerbaijan"
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Bahamas The"
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Bahrain"
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Bangladesh"
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Barbados"
        }
    ]
}
```

Following is my response file:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class BaseResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "code")
  int? status;
  @JsonKey(name: "message")
  String? message;
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AllCountryResponse extends BaseResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "data")
  List<CountryResponse> data;

  AllCountryResponse(this.data);

  //from JSON
  factory AllCountryResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AllCountryResponseFromJson(json);

  //to JSON
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AllCountryResponseToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class CountryResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "id")
  String? id;
  @JsonKey(name: "name")
  String? name;

  CountryResponse(this.id, this.name);
  //from JSON
  factory CountryResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CountryResponseFromJson(json);

  //to JSON
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CountryResponseToJson(this);
}
```

I am able to generate the responses.g dart file.

Following is my mapper class file:

```
class Countries {
  String id,name;
  Countries(this.id,this.name);
}

class AllCountries{
  List<Countries> countries;

  AllCountries(this.countries);
}

extension CountryResponseMapper on CountryResponse? {
  Countries toDomain() {
    return Countries(
        this?.id.orEmpty() ?? EMPTY, this?.name.orEmpty() ?? EMPTY);
  }
}

extension AllCountriesResponseMapper on AllCountryResponse? {
  AllCountries toDomain() {
    return AllCountries(this?.data.map((e) => e.toDomain()).toList() ?? []);
  }
}
```

Once I run my api I do get 200 status while using my bio, but after that it shows me the default error I have set, i.e. "Something went wrong". Which means there is an issue in mapping the response.

Can someone help me with mapping this list please?

Comment: Try at least wrapping your toDomain() methods inside try/catch so we can have proper throwed error. With "Something went wrong" there is really not much for us to do. Update your Q after you get that error from catch please.

Comment: Added try/catch toDomain() methods. But still not getting any errors there.

Comment: That code throws your custom error message and you did not get any error after setting breakpoint inside your catch? That's weird and indicates that problem is in a whole other place inside your app.

Comment: @DavidSedlář could you tell me if this particular response handling code is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.
This code is generated by a very small and simple script (which was written in a few minutes).

```dart
class Response {
  Response(
      {required this.code,
      required this.message,
      required this.count,
      required this.data});

  factory Response.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Response(
      code: json['code'] as int?,
      message: json['message'] as String?,
      count: json['count'] as int?,
      data: json['data'] == null
          ? []
          : (json['data'] as List).map((e) => Data.fromJson(e as Map)).toList(),
    );
  }

  final int? code;

  final String? message;

  final int? count;

  final List<Data> data;

  static List<Response> fromJsonList(List json) {
    return json.map((e) => Response.fromJson(e as Map)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'code': code,
      'message': message,
      'count': count,
      'data': data.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }

  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> toJsonList(List<Response> list) {
    return list.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({required this.id, required this.name});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Data(
      id: json['id'] == null ? 0 : json['id'] as int,
      name: json['name'] == null ? '' : json['name'] as String,
    );
  }

  final int id;

  final String name;

  static List<Data> fromJsonList(List json) {
    return json.map((e) => Data.fromJson(e as Map)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }

  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> toJsonList(List<Data> list) {
    return list.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
  }
}
```

Code generation script:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:object_serializer/json_serializer_generator.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

void main() {
  final classes = loadYaml(_classes) as Map;
  final g = JsonSerializerGenerator();
  final classesCode = g.generateClasses(classes);
  final values = {
    'classes': classesCode,
  };

  var source = g.render(_template, values);
  source = g.format(source);
  File('bin/stackoverflow.dart').writeAsStringSync(source);
}

const _classes = r'''
Response:
  fields:
    code: int?
    message: String?
    count: int?
    data: List<Data>

Data:
  fields:
    id: int
    name: String
''';

const _template = r'''
{{classes}}
''';
```